JUnit5 tests are not discovered using @Suite test
I have recently tried to group my tests by class using the @Suite testing Annotation , but when I try and run these tests they fail with "No Tests found".
To try and use the debugger to trace the problem, I created a custom launcher. I was able to trace the launch setup and it seems to set up a request to the jUnit test engine for each test, but then doesn't execute them.
If I run the test classes individually, they run successfully using Intellij in the editor, maven in the build process, and maven via line commands.
To try and solve this problem, I created a simple project creating three classes, a SimpleTest class, a CustomSuite class, and a CustomTestSuiteLauncher. I have listed these files together with the pom below.
SimpleTest.class
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    void simpleTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("SimpleTest is running");
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}

CustomSuite.class
package org.example;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectClasses({SimpleTest.class})
public class CustomSuite {
}

CustomTestSuiteLauncher
package org.example;


import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherDiscoveryRequest;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory;
import org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors;


public class CustomTestSuiteLauncher {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CustomTestSuiteLauncher.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(
                        DiscoverySelectors.selectClass(SimpleTest.class)
                ).build();
        LOG.info(request.toString());
        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();

        launcher.execute(request);
    }
}


pom.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSuite</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.11.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*SuiteTest.java</include>
                        <include>**/CustomTestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/JFXPixel**.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/JFXPoint**.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



Update
I was able to run CustomSuite using Maven by changing the -DTest arg to -Dinclude=CustomSuite for example the run command command to run this test is
mvn test -Dinclude=CustomSuite

And was able to run the test using CustomTestSuiteLauncher. The run command is:
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.CustomTestSuiteLauncher"

However I am unable to run the test from the Intellij IDE by clicking on the run test Icon next to the class name as in the following screen snapshot.


Your include patterns do not include "CustomSuite", therefore not running it is the expected behaviour.

Oh thankyou. In fact it did run under maven with the command " mvn test -Dinclude=CustomSuiteTest

The only problem I have now is that it wont find any tests in the Intellij editor

Did you do the usual reload/reimport Maven project, clear caches, ect dance with IDEA?

You'll also want to double-check the run configuration IDEA created.

You have to add the <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId> as a supplemental dependency https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/blob/episode-4/episode-4/pom.xml otherwise they can not recognized.

Thank you khmarbaise adding junit-platform-suite-engine resolved the problem
